# Hebrew fonts gone or messed up in v. 12.3

Tags: bugs, front-end, version-12.3

It seems that Hebrew fonts in general are not visible in the Notebooks, for v. 12.3. Sometimes they overwrite neighboring English text. I have checked the fonts, text color, etc. -- nada. If I export to, say, PDF, I *do* see the Hebrew text. I did not see this problem in earlier versions.

This is version 12.3.1.0, on Windows 64-bit.

If this should be posted elsewhere, please let me know.

Thank you.

UPDATE: I posted this bug to WR. Someone wrote back, instructing me to reset it to its default configuration, reactivate, etc. I did all that -- nada. Therefore, I am in the meantime also interested in a workaround. Thanx.

Comment: Where is the code that demonstrates the problem? What is the on-topic question?

Comment: I am sorry that I was not clear.
If I simply open a new Notebook and type in Hebrew, I see the cursor progress, but no letters.
If I first type in English, and then in Hebrew, the latter overwrites the former.
This did not happen with any earlier versions of the Mathematica (Notebook).
If I save this as a PDF, I see all of the Hebrew, and there is no overwriting.
This is version 12.3.1.0, on Windows 64-bit.

Comment: This may be a bug. In that case, contact Wolfram Support. Here, the community expects and curates questions on how to use the software Wolfram Mathematica that can be answered in particular, not just commented. Probably a valid question on your case could be :  "Can you people reproduce this issue and in which platforms?" "Can we force mathematical to use other fonts?" In the meantime, you have shared almost no information. What have you tried? Which is the platform? Put yourself in our place. What can you share that would make us see your problem more easily?

Comment: I have no idea why this should be closed. I have stated the platform. I have written that I tried various fonts and colors. I have detailed (in the comments) how to reproduce the problem.

Comment: What operating system are you using? I have to say I don't think this question is off topic - if nothing else, we have certainly tracked unsolvable-by-the-community bugs here in the past and occasionally find workarounds for them.

Comment: I am able to see and type Hebrew characters in 12.3 on Linux, without any issues. I came across [this old Community post](https://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/1316710) about Hebrew not being well-supported in Mathematica that may be helpful. Have you tried changing the default typing font and seeing if perhaps the font simply doesn't support Hebrew characters on your system?

Comment: (Sorry, I didn't see that you stated your OS and that you had tried other fonts in the comments. Perhaps you can add that info to the question.)

Answer (score 2):

It’s a bug in 12.3 on Windows.

Comment: Do you know that this is a bug, or are you expressing an opinion?

Comment: @bbgodfrey I know that it is a bug.  I also know that it has been fixed in 13.0.

Comment: That's great.  Thanks.

Comment: Thanx all! Now just to wait for v. 13.0 ... . ;-)

Comment: @ihojnicki, BTW, you might want to tell this to the Technical Support folk (in particular: Vamshi Krishna). Thanx.